# Update some contents from another repo into local repo

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have 2 repos - `repoMain` and `repoSub`where I am working on the repoSub..

A couple of months back, repoSub is created as a fork off from repoMain, then a few months later, as repoMain has been updated with some new stuff, right now I had wanted to make sure that repoSub has some of the common/core files to be on the 'same level' as repoMain.

Allow me to cite a simple example (hopefully it can be understand..), 
Eg. 5 items in each repo but their file contents could differ from each other.

- 2 same file names with same contents
- 2 core files with the same name but with different contents
- the last file is a different file, different contents from both repos

As I have been working on repoSub, I had wanted to update the 2 files with the same file name (but their file contents are different) from repoMain, what is the best way to do it so that I can minimize any conflicts/ not have any files in the repoSub be overwritten by repoMain etc?

I tried doing something of the following:

- git remote add mainRepo
- git fetch mainRepo
- git checkout --track mainRepo/master
- ∘ fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
- ∘ Eventually I try out on another branch with a different naming such
  as mainRepo/testBranch
- git checkout master
- git merge testBranch

And I got a bunch of conflict errors etc..

Comment: Conflict error is inevitable when files were modified separately.  There are bunch of guide for solving merge conflict, you can search and read them.

Answer (score 0):

Use checkout form `git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​` to checkout files instead of branches.

```
git checkout --patch repoMain/master -- myFile.java
```

As per the [git-checkout Documentation:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> When <paths> or --patch are given, git checkout does not switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit). In this case, the -b and --track options are meaningless and giving either of them results in an error. The <tree-ish> argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree.
>
> git checkout with <paths> or --patch is used to restore modified or deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace paths with the contents from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit-ish).

> **-p**
>
> **--patch**
>
> Interactively select hunks in the difference between the <tree-ish> (or the index, if unspecified) and the working tree. The chosen hunks are then applied in reverse to the working tree (and if a <tree-ish> was specified, the index).
>
> This means that you can use git checkout -p to selectively discard edits from your current working tree.